# find a way to get a property from DDMFormField

Tags: freemarker, liferay-7

Hi I have a question in liferay 7.4 ,

I am using assetRenderer Class to build a freemarker template.

https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.4-latest/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/dynamic/data/mapping/kernel/DDMFormFieldValue.html

My problem is I cannot get the url from the **featuredImage** field which is an image field in a structure, I get a whole value which is a string, I would like to have another way.

```
<#function getFieldData ddmFormFieldValues fieldReference>
    <#list ddmFormFieldValues as ddmFormFieldValue>
        <#if ddmFormFieldValue.getDDMFormField().getFieldReference()==fieldReference>
            <#if (ddmFormFieldValue)??>
                <#assign value=ddmFormFieldValue />
                <#return value />
            <#else>
                <#return null />
            </#if>
        </#if>
    </#list>
    <#return null />
</#function>


    <#assign ddmFormValuesReader = assetRenderer.getDDMFormValuesReader() />
    <#assign ddmFormFieldValues = 
     ddmFormValuesReader.getDDMFormValues().getDDMFormFieldValues()/>
    <#assign newsImage = getFieldData(ddmFormFieldValues, 'featuredImage') />
    ${newsImage.getValue().getString(locale)}
```

The result will be  a string  like  this :

```
{"extension":"jpg","fileEntryId":"631318","groupId":"630625","title":"Dino-bakgrund.png","type":"document","url":"\/documents\/630625\/0\/Dino-bakgrund.png.jpg\/ecffe3b3-333e-3da3-6bb4-732da3d60947?t=1557132929823&imagePreview=1","uuid":"ecffe3b3-333e-3da3-6bb4-732da3d60947"}
```

Is there a way to get the property directly,  since I get a string here ?
I can convert the String to Json and get the result, but this is not a good way something like this :

```
  <#assign newsImage_map = jsonFactoryUtil.createJSONObject(newsImage) />
      <#if (newsImage_map.url)?? >
            <#assign newsImageUrl = newsImage_map.url />
            ${newsImageUrl }
      </#if>
```

Is there away that I do not covert to JSON ?

Comment: If you stuck with a JSON string anyway, then note that FreeMarker 2.3.31 and later has `?eval_json`, so with that at least you won't need a `jsonFactoryUtil`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice